# Dedication on submission?

Tags: publications, dedication

Suppose I had a professor X Y who was prominent in my field. May I include the dedication "To my teacher professor X Y" in a submission, for a journal which practices blind submissions?

Comment: I would wait until the paper is accepted. (Or you could ask the editor.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably edit that in after review when/if the paper is accepted. Very few papers are published in the form originally submitted. But, as Ethan Bolker notes in a comment, you can also ask the editor.

You could also obfuscate it in the original submission: Dedicated to "omitted", perhaps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the obfuscation suggestion!